# Interface Builder Localization HowTo

Tags: ios, xcode, internationalization, interface-builder

I was digging into Apple Developers' Docs to understand how localization/internationalization of apps should be done and I wanted to understand how Interface Builder helps you managing multiple NIB files for multiple languages... the docs point me to the "localization" section within the *Interface Builder user Guide*, but I can not find it.. should I find it within the Xcode 4 docs? Can someone point me a document that shows you how to implement localization within the Interface Builder/XCode? Where is the "Interface Builder User Guide"?

Thanks in advance.

PS: should I start implementing my app using Localized strings/bundles from the beginning even if I only start with a single language? Is it a pain to "internationalize" an application that has not been developed with multiple languages' support in mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Giani I think you were trying to find this:

http://developer.apple.com/internationalization/

(With more detail: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html )

You should **always** start an app with that in mind. Because later, if your client has the need to add a new language you will have a ton of work. Even if this is app is just for you, you should use it. Besides learning how to do it, you are keeping your code flexible for a sudden change in your requirements.

Comment: It seems a bit complex at the beginning for an unexperienced iOS developer to implement internationalization... but maybe it will become clearer after I read the docs and after trying on a simple test app :) Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Jacky, I have one question for you.... if I want to start a new application and internationalize it from the beginning, is it necessary to do it "by hand" or can I tell Xcode to start with an "internationalized" application? I'm doing a bit of experience with single-view applications and Xcode prepares the nib files and other stuff for you and I'm wondering if I can tell Xcode to prepare the project in a way it can be easily internationalized. I hope my question is quite clear..

Comment: I've seen that it is possible to tell Xcode to internationalize a resource, so I've tried to internationalize the xxx-info.plist file but then the code can not compile because it does not look for it into the en.lproj directory but in the base directory... I think I'll have to carefully read the documentation before understanding how to manage this stuff correctly.. maybe the info.plist file does not need to be internationalized..

Answer (score 2):

I agree with previous comments regarding the complexity of these solutions. Because of that, I have just created a new tool that **automatically localizes your IB files**. Check it out here: https://github.com/angelolloqui/AGi18n

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote a simple category which handles Localisation with IB.

Header file looks like this.

```
@interface UIView (Localization)

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *mainTextKey;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *secondaryTextKey;

- (void)updateMainText;
- (void)updateSecondaryText;

@end
```

Implementation

```
@implementation UIView (Localization)


- (NSString *)mainTextKey{

    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(mainTextKey));

}

- (void)setMainTextKey:(NSString *)mainTextKey{

    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(mainTextKey), mainTextKey, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    [self updateMainText];


}

- (NSString *)secondaryTextKey{

    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(secondaryTextKey));

}

- (void)setSecondaryTextKey:(NSString *)secondaryTextKey{

    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(secondaryTextKey), secondaryTextKey, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    [self updateSecondaryText];
}

- (void)updateMainText{

    //handle all cases one by one

    if([self isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)self;
        label.text= NSLocalizedString(self.mainTextKey, nil) ;
    }else if ([self isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){

        UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)self;
        [btn setTitle:NSLocalizedString(self.mainTextKey, nil)  forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }


}
- (void)updateSecondaryText{
    //handle all cases one by one

}



@end
```

Basic Usage:

1. Create a UIView Element Like UIButton or UIlable
2. Specify your strings key inside UserDefinedAttributes against key "mainTextKey" or "secondaryTextKey".
3. Run the app and it will load proper text from your strings file.

This is written without any proof reading , excuse for any stupid mistakes.